# Create an enum of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I am trying to use enumerations of `std::vector<bool>` because i'd like to represent some values as a vector of bits.

So I tried the following code:

```
enum class ProximityStateEnum : std::vector<bool> {

    Unknown = std::vector<bool>{false,false},

    NotConnected = std::vector<bool>{false,true},

    Connected = std::vector<bool>{true,false},

    ConnectedButNotLatched = std::vector<bool>{true,true}

};
```

But when I compile the code with this, I get the error `underlying type ‘std::vector<bool>’ of ‘ProximityStateEnum’ must be an integral type`. How can I do to create an enum of vectors ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot; `enum`s can only be based on integral types.

If it can be helpful, since C++14 you can use binary literals to specify their values:

```
enum class ProximityStateEnum {
    Unknown = 0b00,
    NotConnected = 0b01,
    Connected = 0b10,
    ConnectedButNotLatched = 0b11
};
```

which is pretty much as clear as your idea, but way more compact and orders of magnitude more efficient than any hypothetical `std::vector` based solution.

Another possibility that is often used in `enum`s where particular bits have particular meaning is to build them with expressions:

```
enum ProximityStateEnum {
    Unknown = 0b00,
    NotConnected = 0b01,
    Connected = 0b10,
    ConnectedButNotLatched = Connected | NotConnected
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In my case, I really need the type to be of type `std::vector<bool>`. i will probably take a look at struct with static members.

Comment: @Xatyrian: sounds like an XY problem, you should probably describe why exactly you need it to be an `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: Also, a `struct` with only static members doesn't make much sense, use a namespace.

Answer (score 4):

`enum` and `enum class` are not meant as aliases to instances of arbitrary objects - they're limited to *integral types*, and every explicit value must be a *constant expression*. See the [cppreference page on `enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for more information.

If you want to give a name to particular instances of `std::vector<bool>`, either use functions or `inline` variables:

```
auto Unknown()                { return std::vector<bool>{false,false}; }
auto NotConnected()           { return std::vector<bool>{false,true}; }
auto Connected()              { return std::vector<bool>{true,false}; }
auto ConnectedButNotLatched() { return std::vector<bool>{true,true}; }

// ...or, in C++17:
inline auto Unknown =                std::vector<bool>{false,false};
inline auto NotConnected =           std::vector<bool>{false,true};
inline auto Connected =              std::vector<bool>{true,false};
inline auto ConnectedButNotLatched = std::vector<bool>{true,true};
```

In your particular use case, you don't really need an `std::vector` because you know the size of your bitset in advance - `std::bitset` or *binary literals* will work well:

```
enum class ProximityStateEnum : /* some suitable type */ 
{
    Unknown =                0b00,
    NotConnected =           0b01,
    Connected =              0b10,
    ConnectedButNotLatched = 0b11
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, `std::bitset` could also be usable but I previously decided to stick with vectors so now I can't really change. Your approach without the enum is interesting, but as I need to group my different values, I think I'd make them static members of structs

Answer (score 0):

As said by other, enums can only be integral types.

If the lenght of your vectors of bool is constant (as in you example, where is 2), you can substitute the `std::vector<bool>` with a `std::array<bool, length>`. One advantage in using `std::array` instead of `std::vector` is that you can define it as `constexpr`.

So a reasonable (IMHO) alternative is define a enum type based on `std::size_t`, with sequential values starting from `0`,

```
enum ProximityStateEnum : std::size_t
 {
    Unknown = 0U,
    NotConnected,
    Connected,
    ConnectedButNotLatched
 };
```

and a `static` `constexpr` `std::array` of `std::arrays` of `bool`

```
// .......................... last value of the enum vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
static constexpr std::array<std::array<bool, 2U>, 1U+ConnectedButNotLatched>
   pseArr { { { {false, false} }, { {false, true} },
              { {true, false} },  { {true, true} } } };
```

that you can use as follows

```
pseArr[NotConnected][0]
```